# Mathematical fraction of text descriptions

Tags: math-mode, fractions, text

[image]

I know exactly how to generate it, but I want a more efficient way. Anybody can help?

```
\begin{equation}
\nonumber
n=\frac{\mathrm{maximum \ fraction \  of \  the  \ river \  that  \ a \  boat \  can \  traverse  \ in  \ a  \ single \  day}}{\mathrm{distance  \ between \  campsites \  as a \  fraction \  of \  total  \ river \  length}},
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @yo' Indeed I had an account before and have already asked several questions here  :-) But I forgot my account...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is really needed, then use `\text{foo foo}` instead of `\mathrm{foo\ foo}`. The `\text` command is designed to display, well, text in a math environment, however it should be restricted to short text, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\nonumber
n=\frac{\text{maximum fraction  of  the  river  that   a   boat   can  traverse  in   a   single   day}}{\text{distance   between   campsites   as a   fraction   of   total   river   length}},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Vinnton Note that you can use `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` or `\[ ... \]` instead of the hack with `\nonumber`.

Comment: @yo': I wouldn't consider `\nonumber` a hack.